# Angular 2 - Change detection is slow in DOM

Tags: cordova, angular

I have a (rather big and complex) web application. We use [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) to wrap it inside a native application.

My problem is that I have a splitter element, it can be dragged and it resizes the element next to it. I create Observable from the drag events of this splitter element and count the width of the element next to it in TypeScript, then bind this to the DOM element like this:

```
[style.width.%]="width$ | async"
```

I use an Observable and async pipe. I have also tried with a simple variable.

The problem with both is that inside the cordova app it happens really slow. I check every row and everything happens as fast as in the browser every computing and all, but when I push the value to the DOM (`width$.next(calculatedWidth)`, or just a simple value) it isn't happening as fast as inside the browser aka. it laggs. I drag the splitter, then I wait like 2-3 seconds and it just jumps to the correct position. Meanwhile the same code inside the browser is just fine and works real time on the same device.

To make things even more odd, I tried to work my way around the change detection and I manipulate the width of the element directly like this:

```
element.nativeElement.style.width = ...;
```

and if I do it like this, then the change happens instantly.

Any and all help is much appreciated, because I can't move on until it is solved. Of course, I could just stay with direct manipulation, but I use DOM binding elsewhere in the app as well, and it's just as slow there too, and it would be very complicated and ugly if I use direct manipulation there as well.

Edit:

Code samples for the below explanations:
http://pastebin.com/spHCjdLQ

To clear things up. I am testing it on an android device with Chrome and a v56.x version System WebView.

For the architecture:

I have a main-app.component which has the splitter, which is controlling the width of the element to the left of it. The event handling and event subscribing is done via Observables

```
Observable.fromEvent(this.splitter.nativeElement, 'mouseDown')...
```

On the right side of the splitter I have an other component let's say a componentLoader. It loads in components dynamically with `*ngComponentOutlet` and it maintaining a service which is available inside the loaded component to check the available space for them to laod in. It is needed in order to make the loaded components responsive to size changes. I know I could implement it in the components too, but I need this in several cases and I wanted to avoid duplication. So, I made a service and the componentLoader give it to the injector and maintaining the values inside it, and the loaded component can listen to changes through an Observable.

The component loader watches it's width with this method:

```
ngDoCheck() {
    let width = this.root.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    this.screenSizeService.width = Math.round(((width / window.innerWidth) * 100));
}
```

On every change detection circle it refreshes the width. As far as I could found this is the only way to watch an elements width with Angular 2, but it's a kind of hacky so if somebody know an other method, then it is really appreciated!

The problem is that as I bind the counted width of the splitted element the width of the other component also change. And both detection runs really slow, BUT only inside the cordova wrapped application. On the browser it works just fine.

The version of the System WebView and the Chore is the same on the device: 56.0.2924.87

Comment: Do you use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`? Did you test in production build or development mode?

Comment: I don't use the OnPush strategy. And I tested it in a production build inside a release android package. I also checked in debug, but the problem persists.

Comment: Debug is known to be slow, especially if a lot of events are fired. `OnPush` is highly recommended if performance is relevant. You might consider to register your event handler outside of Angulars zone. Events listened to within Angulars zone cause application wide change detection to run.

Comment: It's slow even in production. The odd thing is that it is only slow inside the cordova application. If I watch it in Chrome on the same device, then it works correctly and fast.

Comment: Tha other thing is, that I have to listen to an elements width (it is needed  elsewhere for responsive design) and that binds slow as well.

Comment: if your device is iOS, Webviews do not have the same engine as in Chrome.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "listen to an elements width"?

Comment: I test it on an Android device with a 56.x version System WebView.
I have a component which loads in other components dynamicly, the loaded component needs to know how much space they have and I wanted to make a service from itto avoid duplication. So in the loader component I am doing this:
`ngDoCheck() {
        let width = this.root.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
        this.screenSizeService.width = Math.round(((width / window.innerWidth) * 100));
    }`
As far as I could found on the internet it is the only way to observe an elements width with Angular 2.

Comment: what kind of subject is `width$` ? are you sure it does not replay all the values on every subscription ? maybe you could provide the code of the service and your components. because it's hard to figure out what is happening here. there's too much explainations and not enough code...

Comment: It's a BehaviorSubject.
Also, I added a link to the pastebin for the code samples.